# Reorder columns in multidimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, sorting

I have a 3D array that looks like

```
 dat <- array(1:1500, dim = c(10,30,5))
```

with 10 rows, 30 columns and 5 pages in `R`. I would like to manipulate `dat` so that the last column is moved first. More generally, how can I randomly reorder all columns, while keeping the data structure?

Comment: `dat[,c(30,1:29),]`

Comment: oh, is that enough? I feel a bit silly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, once you know how

```
dat <- array(1:60, dim=c(3, 10, 2))

# move last column first
dat[,c(10, 1:9),]
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   28    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22    25
# [2,]   29    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23    26
# [3,]   30    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24    27
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   58   31   34   37   40   43   46   49   52    55
# [2,]   59   32   35   38   41   44   47   50   53    56
# [3,]   60   33   36   39   42   45   48   51   54    57

# arrange columns randomly
dat[,sample(dim(dat)[2]),]
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    7    1   25   28   19    4   10   22   13    16
# [2,]    8    2   26   29   20    5   11   23   14    17
# [3,]    9    3   27   30   21    6   12   24   15    18
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   37   31   55   58   49   34   40   52   43    46
# [2,]   38   32   56   59   50   35   41   53   44    47
# [3,]   39   33   57   60   51   36   42   54   45    48
#
```